# Xcode segue with an UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

In Xcode I can control + mouse drag from a `UIButton` to another `UIViewController`, in order to enable that button to segue to that `UIViewController` when a user presses the button, how can I recreate this property for `UIImageView` ?

I tried changing its traits to Button [Check] and User Interaction Enabled [Check], plus enabling Accessibility, and Enabling User Interaction in the Attributes Inspector, however still, nothing happens when I control + mouse drag from a `UIImageView` to another `UIViewController`.

If possible* I would appreciate a solution that doesn't involve code.

*Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a button.

Assign a image to the button. then make the segue

Answer (score 0):

You can not add segue on `UIImageView`. Add segue from your `UIImageView`'s view controller to your destination view controller. Give tap gesture to your `UIImageView`, in action method of tap gesture use perform segue method.

**See below code**

```
-(void)tapHandeler:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)guesture
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR SEGUE IDENTIFIER" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOUR SEGUE IDENTIFIER"]) {

        // If you want to do any preprocessing, do here
    }
}
```